ASP.NET webforms on .NET 4.8 with Web API : authentication issue - 401 Unauthorized error
I work on a old legacy ASP.NET web forms application on .NET 4.8, which includes a Web API. The web form application uses Windows authentication, but the API must be accessible by any kind of client. I have to disable authentication only for the API, Windows authentication must be remains as it for the webforms application.
Most of clients for the API come from Linux environment.
The web.config is set up like this (only relevant data is pasted):
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
...
...
<location path="~">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="api">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>

I try to add config.SuppressHostPrincipal(); in the WebApiConfig class:
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        config.SuppressHostPrincipal();

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "SaraApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{Action}/{id}",
            defaults: new
            {
                id = RouteParameter.Optional,
                type = RouteParameter.Optional
            }
        );

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
    }
}

I also add [AllowAnonymous] decoration to my controller:
[AllowAnonymous]
public class WebApiController : CustomApiController
{
    // Code...
}

But I still get a 401 - Unauthorized error. The only way I found to get a 200 response is to set in my Windows console test client UseDefaultCredentials = true in HttpClient declaration:
static HttpClient _client = new(new HttpClientHandler() 
                                    { UseDefaultCredentials = true })
                                {
                                    BaseAddress = new Uri("http:// localhost:24650/")
                                };

I guess I can't use this from Linux clients. So I try to find a way to let the API accessible from everyone, without authentication. I will use JWT inside the API to do it.
EDIT :
I think I found the solution. I have to enable Anonymous Authentication in the web application project settings...

Remove config.SuppressHostPrincipal():
This setting bypasses security for the entire application. Since web.config handles API access, it's unnecessary.
Linux Clients:
Linux clients won't have access to default Windows credentials. You'll need to implement JWT authentication in your API to allow access from Linux environments. The client will send a JWT token in the request header for authorization.

Thank you for your reply. config.SuppressHostPrincipal() was used only for few tests, with or without it, unfortunately I still have a 401 - Unauthorized error.
For Linux clients, JWT is token in the request is the solution, you're right

By following this article, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters#combining-authentication-filters-with-host-level-authentication
config.SuppressHostPrincipal() should let me to access to the API without authentication.
